# What is voting fraud?

Tags: discussion

So I just noticed that today I had a rather large gain in reputation, followed by a subsequent large loss of reputation. When I click on the appropriate tab by my profile, it says "Serial voting was reversed". I read a little and it mentioned voting fraud.
What happened and does this mean I am in trouble?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [FYI](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13153/629362). You will be fine (unless you own another account which is responsible for these (up)-votings).

Comment: You can find some basic info about serial voting here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info

Comment: I also got 200 points a few days back and thought it had been a dream when they were gone the next day until I saw the reputation tab.

Comment: @take008 I think I don't understand lots of things about reputation. How can you have over 300 points of reputation without having asked or answered anything? I'm not jealous or anything... I'm just curious!

Comment: @Darsen 11 Q 16 A, maybe you looked at their meta profile :-)